# Log Colors on IntelliJ Run Console

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Having problems to see the colors for logs on the IntelliJ Run Console (windows).

Through Cygwin run, I see logs have different colors, e.g: [image]

On the IntelliJ run Console, same logs show without any colors:
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [GrepConsole](https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole) plugin for IntelliJ supports something like this.

Here's some console output with no use of GrepConsole:

[image]

And here's the same console output again but with GrepConsole configured to render lines containing `INFO` in green and lines containing `ERROR` in red:

[image]

Here's the GrepConsole configuration:

[image]

Note: this does not exactly match what you asked for (highlighting a single word) but it's close and configuring GrepConsole for this behavour is very simple and GrepConsole also offers other useful features such a searching and filtering the console output.

Comment: It does the job!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just wondering how can I make all the log info display in the console or save them in a file so that I can have a look? It seems I can only check part of the info in the console.